# Reversing a string in C using pointers - purpose of if statement?

Tags: c, string

In the code below that reverses a string, I don't understand what is the purpose of the if statement. What case is this if statement trying to catch for?

Isn't this superfluous since you've already set char*end= str, and so the statement if(str) has to be true or your code would have already failed by this point?

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    char *end = str;
    char temp;
    if (str) 
    {
        while (*end)
        {
            end++;
        }
    }
    end--; //pulls back one for \0 character
    while (str < end)
    {
        temp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }    
}
```

Comment: This code is bugged, `end--;` causes undefined behaviour if `str` was null. It needs `if ( !str ) return;` at the start of the function instead, it makes no sense to try and reverse nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prevents dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, very good practice.

In case `str == NULL`, then `*end` will be undefined behavior, so checking that before dereferencing, is really a good thing to do, because ignoring such possibility will cause a bug that will be very hard to detect, except of course using a debugger, but still, why leave the need to track the problem, when you can avoid it at the expense of almost nothing, generally.

It would actually be better to do something like this

```
if (str == NULL)
    return;
```

Comment: The rest of the code surely makes it crash then :P -- it still gets executed. The entire stuff after that test shoild be inside the same set of braces.

Comment: Ahh, I see. So its ok to assign char*end = str even if str is NULL, but as soon as you dereference,  that is when you want to do your check b/c that is undefined behavior (like going into adjacent memory or something with the end++ line). Thanks.

Comment: @Jongware. good point. Seems like maybe the scope of the if statemnt should be more expansive. end-- will still immediately cause a problem if str is NULL. Also wouldn't want to run that while loop if str is NULL

Comment: @Ragnar it won't run any way because if  `end == NULL` then `str == NULL` and `str < end` will be false. But certainle the `end--;` is going to cause the issue.

Comment: @iharob Actually, the `end--` should change the `NULL` address to 0xFFFFFFFF, which would be greater than `str`.

Comment: The `end--` in the question is bad because decrementing a pointer variable before the start of the array leads to undefined behaviour.  You can't tell where the value passed into the function points; decrementing it is wrong if `str` is NULL.  The close brace of the `if` should enclose all the remaining code -- the `end--` and the while loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler exactly or `if (str == NULL) return;`.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't this superfluous since you've already set char*end= str, and so
>   the statement if(str) has to be true or your code would have already
>   failed by this point?

Actually, the line

```
char *end = str;
```

will not cause the "code to fail", even if a null pointer was passed as an argument.  Then it would just assign `NULL` to `end`.

> What case is this if statement trying to catch for?

Since we do not know if we were passed a NULL pointer yet, we should check before dereferencing it.  That is what the if statement is for.

Answer (score 0):

This code would work correctly:

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    if (str != NULL) 
    {
        char *end = str;
        while (*end != '\0')
            end++;
        end--; //pulls back one for \0 character
        while (str < end)
        {
            char temp = *str;
            *str++ = *end;
            *end-- = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

This code would also work:

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) 
        return;
    char *end = str;   // Assumes C99 or later
    while (*end != '\0')
        end++;
    end--; //pulls back one for \0 character
    while (str < end)
    {
        char temp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }
}
```

Both ensure that you never mess with a null pointer.  Decrementing a null pointer as in the original code would lead to catastrophe (or, at least, undefined behaviour).  Don't risk it.

You can also use `strlen()` — carefully ensuring you don't run into problems with an empty string:

```
void reverse(char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL || *str == '\0') 
        return;
    char *end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (str < end)
    {
        char temp = *str;
        *str++ = *end;
        *end-- = temp;
    }
}
```